# Create New Bigquery Table Partitioned on Different Column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some data streaming to a Bigquery table partitioned by timestamp column A (defined in streaming service). Now, for analysis, we want to query data with filters on timestamp column B. So, **it would be great be there is someway we can create a view or table(that is in sync with source table) partitioned on Column B**. I looked into materialized views but they only support same partitioning column as in the source table.

Any workaround or suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to partiton the data in 2 different ways without duplicating the data. Maybe the best you can do is to cluster the table by column B.

Comment: @YunZhang I am fine with duplication but that we have to do manually by scheduling jobs, isn't it? Any way we can sync two table near real time?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything out of the box to support 2 tables in sync but with different partitioning spec. You may have to make the magic happen in you data injection pipeline or schedule job to do the replication.